# Как в фоне сохранять данные, когда они меняются?

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Есть такая проблемка: пользователь во время пользования приложения меняет какие-то данные и их нужно сохранять на сервер (я использую Firebase). Каждый раз везде вызывать функцию для сохранения данных, мне кажется, не самая лучшая идея.

Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы один фоновый процесс висел, и когда меняются какие-либо данные он выполнял их сохранение в Firebase? Если нет, то что можно сделать? Как вообще реализуется сохранение данных на сервер в приложениях?

Comment: 1) Самый простой способ - завести `MainApp` наследуемый от `Application`, он живёт весь цикл пока приложение не убито, из него и можно апдейтить базу по таймеру. 2) Более правильный способ, завести `Service` и проводить всю работу из него в фоне.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы создал какую-то сущность, которая живет вместе с приложением, например `Singleton` может быть или какой-то более продвинутый жизненный цикл этой сущности.

Собственно эта сущность должна либо в себе хранить эти данные, либо иметь доступ к БД. Можно сделать реализацию паттерна `Observer` и всякий раз когда дергается тот или иной метод который потенциально может изменить данные, эта сущность будет проверять изменились ли они? Если да то отправлять на сервак.

Другой вариант, если вы не хотите отправлять запрос на сервак всякий раз когда что-то меняется, то можно создать какую-нибудь логику, которая хранит изменения локально и отправляет их на сервак раз в **N** минут. Но тут надо еще понимать, что если пользователь закроет приложение вам надо иметь возможность их отправить либо при закрытии либо отправить при повторном открытии.

Comment: Возможно это как-то можно красиво оформить с помощью rxjava. С ним пока только знакомлюсь) Но вот последний вариант, который вы предложили, мне пока большего всего нравится, потому что так можно ещё и экономить на запросах к Firebase))

Comment: Ну RxJava это ваш Observer. По сути вы создаете какой-то Observable, который к примеру каждые 2 минуты чекает изменения и если они есть то отправляет запрос на сервак. При входе в приложение например по дефолту синкать данные. Ну это как-то грубо. Тут много вариантов. А как это в коде написать, надо смотреть конкретную реализацию